# Find Missing Numbers

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, left-join

Have a list of product photographs that are positioned in the app.

However, it has come to light that there are some that do not have a position of 1 set.

Is there a way to retrieve the productID for all the products that do not have a position set to 1?

A quick test on a temp table below. You can see that prodID 95 does not have a position of 1.

```
DECLARE @prodphoto TABLE 
(
ProdID INT,
StatusID INT,
Position INT
)

INSERT INTO @prodphoto VALUES (95,1,2)
INSERT INTO @prodphoto VALUES (95,1,3)
INSERT INTO @prodphoto VALUES (95,1,4)
INSERT INTO @prodphoto VALUES (95,1,5)
INSERT INTO @prodphoto VALUES (95,1,6)
INSERT INTO @prodphoto VALUES (112,1,1)
INSERT INTO @prodphoto VALUES (112,1,2)
INSERT INTO @prodphoto VALUES (112,1,3)
INSERT INTO @prodphoto VALUES (666,1,2)
INSERT INTO @prodphoto VALUES (666,1,3)
```

My desired output would be something like

http://s4.postimg.org/57dh9neql/output.png

I've had a go at left joining to a temp table of positions but I am not getting what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very smart, but simple to read and understand:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProdID
FROM @prodphoto pp
WHERE ProdID NOT IN (SELECT ProdID FROM @prodphoto WHERE Position = 1)
```

Alternatively, with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  pp.ProdID
FROM    @prodphoto AS pp
GROUP BY pp.ProdID
HAVING  SUM(CASE WHEN Position = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Etc. Many roads lead to Rome. :-)

Comment: Many thanks Jeroen.  You don't want to see some of the ideas I was coming back with.

Answer (score 1):

Get all rows from your table and use `union all` to add the rows that are missing.

```
select P.ProdID,
       P.StatusID,
       P.Position as ProdPosition,
       P.Position
from @prodphoto as P
union all
select P1.ProdID,
       null,
       null,
       1
from @prodphoto as P1
where not exists (
                 select *
                 from @prodphoto as P2
                 where P1.ProdID = P2.ProdID and
                       P2.Position = 1
                 )
group by P1.ProdID
order by ProdID, 
         Position
```